# Zeroes of complete L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions, analytic-number-theory

Hello,

Let $F$ and $G$ be two functions belonging in the Selberg class, $\Lambda_{F}$ and $\Lambda_{G}$ the complete L-functions associated to $F$ and $G$. I would like to know whether this assertion is true or not:

"$\Lambda_{F}$ and $\Lambda_{G}$ have the same zeroes if and only if $F=G$ or $F=\overline{G}$."

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $F$ is in the Selberg class, so is $F^2$, $F^3$, etc. So, I think you need to assume $F$ and $G$ are primitive to ask this question.

Comment: When I write "the same zeroes", I mean "the same zeroes with the same multiplicity for $\lambda_{F}$ and $\Lambda_{G}$", so that I don't think it's necessary to assume $F$ and $G$ are primitive.

Comment: Maybe this is a naive comment, but why doesn't your conclusion follow from the Explicit Formula?

Comment: Major typo: you write F=G or F=G !! This can't be what you intended; please edit!

Comment: Zen, I see no typo: can't you see the overline on $G$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on Stopple's comment above, I believe the following argument based on Landau's explicit formula answers the question.

Here is a generalization of Landau's explicit formula for the zeros of the Riemann zeta-function which is exercise 8.4.8 in M. Ram Murty's book *Problems in Analytic Number Theory*: Let $F$ be in the Selberg class, $n>1$ be a positive integer, and $T>1$. Then 
$$ \sum_{|\gamma|\leq T} n^\rho = -\frac{T}{\pi}\Lambda_F(n) + O( n^{3/2}\log T )$$
where $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$, $\beta>0$, runs over the non-trivial zeros of $F(s)$. Here the coefficients $\Lambda_F(n)$ are defined by
$$ -\frac{F'}{F}(s) = \sum_{n=1} \frac{\Lambda_F(n)}{n^s}.$$

Now suppose that $F$ and $G$ are in the Selberg class and have the same zeros (with multiplicity). Then we deduce from Landau's formula that
$$ |\Lambda_F(n) - \Lambda_G(n)| \ll \frac{n^{3/2}\log T}{T} $$
for all $n>1$. Letting $T\rightarrow \infty$, it follows that 
$\Lambda_F(n) = \Lambda_G(n)$ for all $n>1$. This implies that $F=G$.

Comment: By the way, has such a generalization of Landau's explicit formula been proven for automorphic L-functions?